# How refresh a WebBrowser Control MS Access

Tags: ms-access, browser, vba

How refresh a webbrowser control on MS Access 2010?

I'm trying this:

```
Private Sub Btn_Report_Click()
   'Create the report HTML...
   Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
   Set objFile = objFSO.CreateTextFile("C:\Windows\Temp\test_report.html")
   message= "Test of line on variable"
   objFile.WriteLine (message)
   objFile.WriteLine ("This is the second line")
   objFile.Close
End Sub
```

The webcontrol have this on Control Source property

```
="C:\Windows\Temp\test_report.html"
```

Thank you,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did it.

```
Show_Report.SetFocus
SendKeys "{F5}"
```

Where  Show_Report is the name of the Control: WebBrowser Control from MS Access.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

When the ControlSource property of webBrowser control is changed/updated it refreshes the webBrowser control on the form automatically.

Having said that you can use the below trick (generate random number at the end of url)

```
Form_frm_Codes.WebBrowser.ControlSource = "=""D:\abcd.html?rnd=" & Int((300 - 200 + 1) * Rnd + 200) & """"
```

Comment: MS Access WebBrowserControl does not have this.

Comment: @user2607028 How did you put the WebBrowser Control ? The image is the view of Object Browser in code section (Ctrl + F2).

Comment: I use the control from the toolbar of MS Access. just that. It is WebBrowserControl Object. It work perfect but I have to give right clic and refresh ...

Comment: @user2607028 Let me check again. I will get back to you.

Answer (score 1):

Very late, however:

```
wWebBrowserControl.Object.Refresh
```

Comment: This solution works for other types of documents as well, eg txt, docx, bmp, etc

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was referring to a local file which only started to exist after creating a certain button. I solved it by:

```
Webbrowser1.ControlSource = "=""about:blanc"""
Webbrowser1.ControlSource = "=""N:\My Documents\test.xml"""
```